# Recursively filter and map a list of properties

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, reflection

I'm using Kotlin reflection to check if attributes that have a certain annotation are null.

Given the following example:

```
data class DataClass(
    @SomeRandomAnnotation
    val otherAnnotated: String?,
    val inner: InnerClass
)

data class AnotherDataClass(
    @SomeRandomAnnotation
    val annotatedProperty: String?,
    val dataClass: DataClass
) {

    fun checkCreditAnalysisConstrain() {
        print(checkConstrain(this))
    }
}
```

And the function that checks it:

```
fun checkConstrain(parentClass: Any): List<String> {
    val filter = parentClass::class.memberProperties.filter {
        if (memberIsDataClass(it)) checkConstrain(getMemberPropertyInstance(parentClass, it))

        hasAnnotation(it) && propertyIsNull(it, parentClass)
    }
    return filter.map { formatResult(parentClass, it) }
}
```

The idea is that the function is going to iterate through the attributes of my classes checking if they have the annotation and checking if the value is null.
If the property is a data class, the code evaluates the properties of the childs, recursively.

After that, I map the results, transforming the KProperty's into a simple String that is human readable, containing the class name and the attribute name.

The problem is that the above code does not work as expected. The properties returned are only the properties from the first-level class.

If, instead of doing a filter, I just run a forEach and print the result, I get the expected attributes. So I'm pretty sure it's related to the recurring inside a filter.

Do you see any way of doing this in a more functional way? I'm just concerned I won't need a "temp" list and add values to the list and reset it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function recursively calls itself, but does nothing with the returned list of that recursive call. That's why you only get results for the top-level class.

Also, in my opinion, you shouldn't rely on side effects happening from your `filter` call. It probably works, but the function's documentation does not provide a guarantee that it will be called exactly once per item in the collection. So there should be a separate for-loop to do the recursive calls, and the result should be added onto existing results.

```
fun checkConstrain(parent: Any): List<String> {
    val memberProperties = parent::class.memberProperties
    var result = memberProperties
        .filter { hasAnnotation(it) && propertyIsNull(it, parent) }
        .map { formatResult(parent, it) }
    memberProperties.filter { memberIsDataClass(it) }
        .mapNotNull { getMemberPropertyInstance(parent, it) }
        .forEach { result += checkConstrain(it) }
    return result
}
```

You didn't provide code for several of the functions you used. This is what I used for them:

```
val KProperty<*>.returnTypeClass get() = this.returnType.classifier as? KClass<*>
fun <T> memberIsDataClass(member: KProperty<T>) = member.returnTypeClass?.isData == true
fun <T> getMemberPropertyInstance(parent: Any, property: KProperty<T>) = property.getter.call(parent)
fun <T> hasAnnotation(property: KProperty<T>) = property.annotations.firstOrNull { it.annotationClass == SomeRandomAnnotation::class } != null
fun <T> propertyIsNull(property: KProperty<T>, parent: Any) = getMemberPropertyInstance(parent, property) == null
fun formatResult(parent: Any, property: KProperty<*>) = "$parent's property(${property.name}) is annotated with SomeRandomAnnotation and is null."
```